# Jquery get and set sliding element text dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a ul list with list items. Now the very first list item slides over the other list items as defined by a jquery sliding image function. See my markup

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="ei-slider-thumbs">
    <li class="ei-slider-element"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vertical Sunbed</a><img src="images/thumbs/sunbedSmall.jpg" alt="Vertical Sunbed Tan Can" /></li>
    <li><a href="#">Koebana Spray Tan</a><img src="images/thumbs/koebanaSmall.jpg" alt="Koebana Spray Tan" /></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ozone Sauna</a><img src="images/thumbs/ozoneSmall.jpg" alt="Ozone Sauna" /></li>
    <li><a href="#">Glycopeels</a><img src="images/thumbs/3.jpg" alt="thumb03" /></li>
    <li><a href="#">Specialized Facials</a><img src="images/thumbs/4.jpg" alt="thumb04" /></li>
    <li><a href="#">Make Up</a><img src="images/thumbs/5.jpg" alt="thumb05" /></li>
    <li><a href="#">Slide 7</a><img src="images/thumbs/7.jpg" alt="thumb07" /></li>
</ul>
```

Now the list item with class="ei-slider-element", slides over the other list elements. I basically want to set the text in the moving element to the text in the static list item on which the moving element lands... How do I do that? The [EXAMPLE](http://lamininbeauty.co.za/index2.html)
Here is the part governing the moving animation:

**JS**:

```
// thumbs wrapper
this.$sliderthumbs = this.$el.find('ul.ei-slider-thumbs').hide();
// slider elements
this.$sliderElems = this.$sliderthumbs.children('li');
// sliding div
this.$sliderElem = this.$sliderthumbs.children('li.ei-slider-element');
// thumbs
this.$thumbs = this.$sliderElems.not('.ei-slider-element');
// initialize slideshow
this._init(options);​
```

Thank You!

Comment: thank you very much for your effort, but not sure if you understood my question. The slider function works well, but all I need is the active slider's text to change to the text inside the element it slides over(so Slider TExt will first be 'Vertical Sunbed', then 'Koebana Spray Tan' etc... It seems like you know Jquery quite well, don't think you'll have a problem doing that?

Comment: don't think you need to be a pro, just thought if you could build all that code by yourself(in the fiddle) the actual problem I explained would not be difficult for you to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:  on line 326 of http://lamininbeauty.co.za/js/jquery.eislideshow.js I think you should add a [complete] handler that looks something like this

```
// "sliding div" moves to new position
this.$sliderElem.stop().animate({
    left : this.$thumbs.eq( pos ).position().left
}, this.options.speed, this.$sliderElem.html($currentSlide.text() ))
```

Then once your slider thing has finished animating it grabs the `currentSlide` text and sets it as the `sliderElem` innerHTML.  I can't test it, but do you get my intention?